# Using the Facebook Graph API why is it possible to read a list of videos posted to an event but not a list of photos?

Tags: facebook, video, facebook-graph-api, photos

As far as I can make out from reading the Facebook Graph API documentation for Events -

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/

...it is possible to get a list (array) of videos that have been added to an event but NOT a list of photos. Why am I not able to get photos belonging to an event? Am I missing something here?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's because the current implementation of the Graph API does not have the connection from Page Event to photos. The only "image" connection is the `picture` connection.  This is probably because they haven't got around to expanding their API to handle all cases.  The `videoes` connection is definitely out of the ordinary.  It may have been placed in there early on in the development of the Graph API to hand one specific facebook partner's needs.

Answer (score 1):

I can get a list of Photos by issuing a /{eventid}/photos request for an event that was created by my app, some event graph api calls are dependent on the fact that your app created the event. i.e. you can't edit an event that wasn't created with your app. I think for the photos request, you need read_stream, user_events, and maybe friend_events permission..